# Find the set of all complex numbers $z$ such that, $1,z,1+z^2$ are collinear.

Tags: complex-numbers

Find the set of all complex numbers $z$ such that, $$1,z,1+z^2$$
are collinear.

Ideas,,

I dont know how start it.

Comment: do you mean *all complex numbers $z$* ?

Comment: yes, I am sorry

Comment: What is your level in math ? Are you new to complex numbers ?

Comment: yes, new.. :( ...

Comment: Well finding this set might not be very easy then, but surely you can find a part of it, for example what happens if $z=3$ ? Can you generalise ?
Then, if you write $z=a+ib$, what is $z^2$ and $1+z^2$ ?
From then, how can you check if three points on a graph are colinears ?

Comment: @Kaster this is not the whole set though, only a part of it =)

Comment: Literally all of them, because any two points are collinear.

Comment: Take $z=i$, then the three points are not collinear.

Comment: Yes indeed. Carefull though, we need $1,z,1+z^2$ to be colinears, not $z=k\cdot 1$

Comment: Ok guys I need to go to sleep. I'll give you a gift : $1+i$ 
Good night =)

Comment: @Furrane how's $1+i$ collinear with 1?

Comment: @Kaster $\mathbb R^2$ is just as good of a representation of $\mathbb C$ as $\mathbb E^2$.

Comment: OK:  The distinct numbers s $a, b, c$ are collinear in the complex plane if the vector from  $a$ to $c$ is a scalar multiple of the vector from $a$ to  $b$.  Thus ${(c-a)}/{(b-a)}$ is to be a real number, the quotient has to have zero imaginary part.  Does this help?

Comment: @eyeballfrog I see. Was thinking about these numbers as vectors, which makes OP's question less meaningful, so I guess you're (and everyone answering) right.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the real & imaginary parts of each number $1=(1,0)$, $z=(x,y)$ and $1+z^2=(1+x^2-y^2,2xy)$. If these points are colinear then they will have the same gradient between them so
\begin{eqnarray*}
m= \frac{y}{x-1}= \frac{y(2x-1)}{1+x^2-y^2-x}
\end{eqnarray*}
Firstly note that $y=0$ is a solution & corresponds to $z$ being real & all three numbers lying on the real line.
Now after a little algebra $y^2=x(2-x)$ and which can be written as $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$ So the other solution is a circle of radius one centered at $1$.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that if $z$ is real then the three points lie on a line
(the real axis), so we may assume that $z$ is not real.

Then the three points are collinear **iff** there is some real $t$ such
that $1+z^2 = (1-t) 1 + t z$, and we see that this is true **iff**
$t= {z^2 \over z-1}$ and $t$ is real.

We see that ${z^2 \over z-1}$ is real **iff** $z^2(\bar{z}-1)$ is real.

Letting $z=re^{i\theta}$ we see that $z^2(\bar{z}-1)$ is real **iff** $r^2 \sin \theta =  \sin (2 \theta)$ **iff** $r = 2 \cos \theta$ and $ r \ge 0$.

Since this gives $z=r e^{i \theta} = 1+\cos(2 \theta)+i\sin(2 \theta)$
we see that the solution is
$\mathbb{R} \cup \{ z | |z-1| = 1 \}$.

Comment: we are answering the same question again ! Nice to see you again ... I get lost on the last line of your answer & cannot reconcile it with my answer.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit: Hi Donald! I was missing an $i$.

Answer (score 0):

By shifting the line by $-1$, we see that the question is the same as asking when
$$0,z - 1, z^2$$
are collinear. This happens if and only if $z^2$ is a scalar multiple of $z - 1$, i.e.
$$z^2 = c(z - 1)$$
for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Clearly this holds when $z = 1$. If $z \neq 1$, the statement holds if and only if
$$\textrm{Im}\left(\frac{z^2}{z - 1}\right) = 0.$$
You can work this out for a more explicit description if desired.

Comment: Or, from the second equation then solve by quadratic formula to get $z = \frac{1}{2}(c \pm \sqrt{c^2 - 4c})$.  If $c^2 - 4c \ge 0$ this just gives a real number; if $c^2 - 4c < 0$ then $z = \frac{1}{2}(c \pm i \sqrt{4c - c^2}) = x \pm i \sqrt{2x - x^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

A classical condition for 3 complex numbers $z_1,z_2,z_3$ to be aligned ([Equation of line in form of determinant](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2111593)) is :

$$\det\begin{pmatrix}z_1&z_2&z_3\\\bar z_1&\bar z_2&\bar z_3\\1&1&1\end{pmatrix}=0$$

Taking $z=re^{i t}$, this condition becomes:

$$\begin{vmatrix}1&re^{i t}&1+r^2 e^{2it}\\1&re^{-i t}&1+r^2 e^{-2it}\\1&1&1\end{vmatrix}=0$$

Which is equivalent, after development, and using Euler formulas, to this equation:

$$-2i r^2 \sin t (r-2 \cos t)=0 $$

which gives rise to 3 types of solutions:

- $r=0$ i.e., point $0$.
- $\sin t=0 \iff t=k \pi$ : all real $z$, i.e., the $x$ axis.
- $r=2 \cos t$ that corresponds to all $z$ belonging to the circle with center in $(1,0)$ with radius 1.

Explanation for the circle: if $z=r e^{it}$ is such that $r=2 \cos t$, we can write: $z=2 \cos t e^{it}=(e^{-it}+e^{it})e^{it}$  (using Euler formula for $\cos t$); thus, expanding : $z=1+e^{2it}$ which is clearly the translated curve of unit circle by vector $(1,0)$.